# React ID Swiper not working with fixed swiper-slide width, height and slidesPerView

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Setting fixed width, height for swiper-slides not working with SlidesPerView and spaceBetween props.

If I remove the swiper-slide fixed width's and height's then the Swiper works as expected.

[Actual Swiper reference](https://kidjp85.github.io/doc/get-started/)

[Code Tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-leavitt-nrb8m)

```
const Container = styled.div`
  height: 300px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

<Swiper slidesPerView={1.5} freeMode spaceBetween={20}>
   <Container>Slide 1</Container>
   <Container>Slide 2</Container>
   <Container>Slide 3</Container>
   <Container>Slide 4</Container>
   <Container>Slide 5</Container>
   <Container>Slide 6</Container>
</Swiper>
```

Expected result swiper should work smoothly even if the fixed widths and heights are passed with slidesPerView and spaceBetween prop combinations.

Comment: What did you do, to move on with this?

Answer (score 0):

The SwiperSlide may have a width on it if you're using the included default CSS